# It's possible to prohibit implicit cast in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, types, casting

We all know that C++ is a weakly typed language. It is not always convenient and intuitive. For example, an implicit cast from a double to an int leads to a loss of precise.
Any ideas about workarounds?

Comment: There is no such thing as an implicit cast. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. A conversion can be implicit or explicit.

Comment: @Pete Becker, a double can be assigned to a float without an explicit cast, wouldn't that be implicit? The terminology for conversion between numeric types is still to call it casting i.e. (double) or static_cast<double>.

Comment: @keith -- the terminology for conversion between numeric types is **conversion**. The terminology for casting is **casting**. Yes, `(double)x` and `static_cast<double>(x)` are casts; they tell the compiler that you want to **convert** the value of `x` to type `double`.

Comment: With Visual-C++ your specific example should trigger [warning C4244: conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-2-c4244). If not, increase the warning level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler can forbid such conversions. With GnuCC and Clang:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
```

will raise warning converted to compilation error when a conversion may loss precision.